# rfid-rc522 Tag is not read

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, rfid

I am using the instructions of https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-rfid-rc522/ to learn how to read my rfid-rc522.

I installed all the things needed, and cloned from git all the files. I connected accordingly and double checked the wire.

The code in Write.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        text = raw_input('New data:')
        print("Now place your tag to write")
        reader.write(text)
        print("Written")
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I run it- The result stops after "Now place your tag to write" and nothing happens when I place my tag. Any help please? What's wrong here? The module gives red light meaning it is connected. Is it really connected? How do I know? Please help.

Edit: My title and tags were wrong in this question due to already saved data. I edited. :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be multiple reasons why your reader is not retrieving any data:

- The **RFID cards** that you are providing to the reader are **not supported** by the *ISO 14443*: Mifare Classic, 4K. (Some DesFire, etc...) are the cards you want to try. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_14443
- The **MFRC522** is not receiving enough **input voltage**. Try to **increase** from 3.3V to 4V. I have tried with 5V months and the reader is still running perfectly, but be cautious. The safe range in NXP is from **2.5V** to **3.6V**. Source: https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MFRC522.pdf
- The **library** you are using does **not support IRQ** (Interruption Request). This means the process of reading UIDs is high CPU consuming and low in performance. **Try to use** this popular library which supports interruptions: https://github.com/ondryaso/pi-rc522 . You will need to **connect another wire** from the IRQ pin in the MFRC522 to one GPIO pin in the Raspberry that is free and supports reading/writing operations.
- Check if **SPI interfaces** are **enable** in Raspbian. Open a terminal and run:

  ls -l /dev/*spi*
- Lastly, it could be that your **reader is broken**. Some chinese versions do not work as they should do. Maybe you should buy another one and try more luck.

I suppose you have connected all cables in the correct way between the MFRC522 and the Raspberry Pi. Check that again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The problem is already solved. The problem was due to soldering, it didn't get voltages right for that. I re-soldered again and it worked just fine. I appreciate your help a lot :)